# How can I place HTML in a JavaScript string and have it validate?

Tags: css, validation, xhtml, layout

I want to show different css files depending on browser that user is using. I want to do this on JS and on client side.
I am using code like this.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")) >= "0"){
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.IE.css\" type=\"text/css\" 
 }
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrom")) >= "0"){
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.chrome.css\" type=\"text/css\" />");
 }
```

*The only problem that I this code is not valid. How I can solve the problem. If I check this document with w3 checker. it will show now:
Line 22, Column 90: document type does not allow element "link" here*****

```
…nt.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/common.IE.css' type='text/css' />");
```

***Line 25, Column 35: an attribute value must be a literal unless it contains only name characters***

```
document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.chrome.css\"…
```

Comment: What about user agents that don't support JavaScript or who have it turned off? (which is getting more and more common) This seems like something that should be done server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

break it up in sub-strings so that it does not get detected ..

```
document.write("<l" + "ink ...
```

or add comments like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--

if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")) >= "0"){
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.IE.css\" type=\"text/css\" 
 }
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrom")) >= "0"){
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.chrome.css\" type=\"text/css\" />");
 }


//-->
</script>
```

Comment: The first one is kind of a backwards approach for readability when there are modern solutions available. Also, I think CDATA is the best way to wrap it, rather than use the old style JavaScript commented out HTML comments.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap that block in [CDATA tags](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

So it looks like like...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")) >= "0"){
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.IE.css\" type=\"text/css\" 
 }
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrom")) >= "0"){
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/common.chrome.css\" type=\"text/css\" />");
 }
]]>
<script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea. Can you tell us your *real* issues which are causing you to serve different stylesheets to different browsers?

You should strive to serve all browsers with one stylesheet, and maybe an additional to IE with CondComs ( sounds like condoms ).

Comment: Haha, we *do* need protection from IE :P